# What the difference between "Did you hear..?" and "Have you heard..?"

Tags: tenses

Q: ____ you ____ about the accident last week?
A: Yes, the boys were driving along Court Street when a motorcycle hit the car.

Comment: These expressions are used interchangeably.

Comment: I think there is a *slight* difference in meaning.  "Did you hear ..." is neutral, and means what it says, while "Have you heard ..." can carry the implication that something has become fairly widely known, and the person is being asked whether they are up to speed on the news.

Comment: To add:  "Have you heard ..." is more usually used to ask half a question ... so you could say "Have you heard about Mrs Jones?", and if the answer is "No" then you can provide detail.  You're being respectful of your audience, who may well have heard, so you check.

Comment: related: [“Have you heard?” vs “Did you hear?” and “Sally ... ”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190435/have-you-heard-vs-did-you-hear-and-sally-broke-has-broken-her-leg)

Answer (score 3):

Did you hear: seems to apply authenticity and directly asking them, did you?
Where as have you heard is little polite, I would say.

Both are used interchangeably.