# “Has only been living” vs “Has been only living”

Tags: adverb-position, only

I encountered this question in a test today, I'm not sure about the differences between the two cases and how the native speakers will use it. Please help me.

> A: Have you heard the gossip? Atarah is moving again.
> B: Really? So soon? She **has only been** living here for three months. It can't be that bad!
>
> 1. has been only  2. has only been 3. only has been

[image]

Comment: Related: **1** [“Have you heard?” vs “Did you hear?” and “Sally broke/has broken her leg”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190435/have-you-heard-vs-did-you-hear-and-sally-broke-has-broken-her-leg) and **2** [Correct position of "only"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only)

Comment: There are **only 11 results** for the phrase [*"have been only"*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22have+been+only%22) in the archives.  This should tell you that the *only* best suited answer is "has only been”. But you could also say "She has been living here for **only** three months”

Comment: Thank you a lot @Mari-LouA