# Did you brush? vs Have you brushed?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, simple-past

> A: You ate this. Have you brushed your teeth?
>   B: You ate this. Did you brush your teeth?

Sentence A is in the Simple Past, while B is in the Present Perfect.
Which sentence is more natural?

Comment: Neither example. 'This' doesn't exist as such. It's been eaten. I suppose it works with certain prior contexts. //  The question "Which sounds more natural: A.  'Have you brushed your teeth? B: Did you brush your teeth?"? may possibly be answered differently in general by people depending on which side of the Atlantic they are. // The questions in 'You ate all those sweets. Have you brushed ... / Did you brush ...? both sound idiomatic to me (a Brit).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, couldn't "this" refer to a partially eaten cake or something? It works just fine in my mind with a construction like, "Did you eat this?" even if there's still some left, so I see no problem with using it here. Distinguishing between "all of this" and "some of this" seems a bit picky.

Comment: @vpn It is a recurring problem that 'Which sounds more natural?-style questions' don't use sentences that _can_ sound natural. 'You ate this' doesn't sound at all natural to me. A simple change of example (as I suggest) helps focus on the real issue.

Comment: [This duplicate {though poorly presented} question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337528/difference-between-did-and-have) was closed for lack of research / better fit on ELL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "Have you seen this?" and "Did you see this?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/what-is-the-difference-between-have-you-seen-this-and-did-you-see-this)

Answer (score 1):

To me, the two sentences are equally natural, but express somewhat different ideas. The first, in the present perfect, means "Have you brushed your teeth since you ate it [i.e., at any time between then and now]?". The second, in the simple past, means "Did you brush your teeth after you ate it [i.e., in the past, soon after you ate it]?".